# Randomizing a matrix multiple times

Tags: r, permutation

I have a data some high throughput gene data represented by matrix `A`

```
          C1 C2 C3 C4
 Gene A   3  5  7  4
 Gene B   2  4  9  3
 Gene C   1  6  8  5
```

and I wish to continually randomize this matrix, say 10 times, and save each of the new randomized matrices as a new object in R. So I would randomize `A` into `A1` , `A2`, ... `A10` and then I would be able to save these retrieve `A1`,,...`A10` whenever I need to. I know that I can randomize `A` row wise by using `A1 <- A[,sample(ncol(A))]` to give me `A1`, which might look like the following:

```
         [1] [2] [3] [4] 
Gene A    5   3   4   7  
Gene B    9   4   3   2
Gene C    5   8   6   1
```

Is it possible to automatically generate more row wise permutations of A, rather than inputting that line of code manually again and again?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `replicate`to randomize the `matrix` 'n' times.  We specify `simplify=FALSE` to get a `list` output.

```
n <- 10
lst <- replicate(n, A[,sample(ncol(A))], simplify=FALSE)
names(lst) <- paste0('A', seq(n))
lst$A1
#       C1 C2 C4 C3
#Gene A  3  5  4  7
#Gene B  2  4  3  9
#Gene C  1  6  5  8
```

If we are sampling by row independently, as @Frank mentioned in the comments, we can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to do the `sample`ing by row.  We can change the column names of the output to the column names of the original matrix ('A').

```
lst <- replicate(n, t(apply(A,1,sample)) , simplify=FALSE)
names(lst) <- paste0('A', seq(n))
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) {colnames(x) <- colnames(A); x})
lst$A1
#       C1 C2 C3 C4
#Gene A  7  4  3  5
#Gene B  2  4  9  3
#Gene C  5  8  1  6
```

#### data

```
A <- structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 5L), 
.Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(
c("Gene A", "Gene B", "Gene C"), c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")))
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're sampling correctly. I get the impression that each row should be independent, like `replicate(10, t(apply(m,1,sample)) )`

Comment: @Frank  I was also confused by OP's code `DataRN[,sample(ncol(A))]`  It is not clear what `DataRN` is.

Comment: Yes, I think @Frank is correct. I want to do some permutation testing, so I would like to randomize each row independently. Also I just edited my post, DataRN[,sample(ncol(A))] should in fact be A[,sample(ncol(A))]

Comment: @NelLau Thanks for the reply.  I was following your code.  Corrected.

Comment: @akrun thanks for your help. Just a couple quick questions about `lst <- replicate(n, t(apply(A,1,sample)) , simplify=FALSE)`. When I used that code, it seems like the original matrix has been randomised into the form of a vector. Is there a way to retrieve each randomised vector individually and also convert it into a matrix or dataframe, just in case I want to look at each matrix separately? And is there a way to add in the colnames that were in the original matrix `A` to each of the new randomised matrices?

Comment: @NelLau I am not getting a `vector` as output.  It is still a matrix with column names removed.  `lapply(lst, function(x) {colnames(x) <- colnames(A); x})`

Comment: @akrun, Ah, yes, I think you're right, that's my mistake about the vectors. But I'm still not sure whether there's a way to go in and view a specific permutation (so like permutation 1, or 2, etc.). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @NelLau I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @NelLau Did you mean the index instead of the value?  If that is the case `replicate(n, t(apply(col(A), 1, sample)), simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: @akrun So after randomizing `A` 10 times using `lst <- replicate(n, t(apply(A,1,sample)) , simplify=FALSE)`  for example, there should be 10 matrices which are all randomized differently contained in the object `lst` if I understand your code correctly. When I use `View(lst)` I only see the first randomized matrix out of the 10. If possible I wish to view each of these matrices separately and perhaps store them as separate objects. Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: @NelLau It is better to keep this in a list rather than having many different objects in the global environment.  You can do most of the operations within the list itself.  Suppose you want to save each `list` elements as separate .csv files, `lapply(names(lst), function(x) write.csv(lst[[x]], paste0(x, '.csv'), quote=FALSE))` If you insist on having separate objects, `list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv); A1`

Comment: @NelLau  To view the objects individually, `View(lst[[2]])` or `View(lst[[1]])`.  You can just do `lst[[1]]` or `lst[[2]]` on the console to print it.